# Computation Hasse unit index for biquadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For a totally real (resp. imaginary) biquadratic number field $K$ with quadratic subfields $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$, is there an explicit method to determine Hasse unit index $(U_K:U_{K_1}U_{K_2}U_{K_3})$?

Comment: The Hasse unit index of $L/K$ is $[\mathcal{O}_L^\times :\mathcal{O}_{L,torsion}^\times \mathcal{O}_{K}^\times]$ ?

Comment: Are you looking for the Brauer-Kuroda formula like in Proposition (4.1) in de Smit's article www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/prep/braukur.ps ?

Comment: H. Wada, On the class number and the unit group of certain algebraic number fields, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo 13 (1966), 201–209

Comment: Is it possible to have a scan of Wada's paper. It is pretty impossible to find it.